# Finding probability of the a coin flip sequence

Tags: probability

Probability of coming heads is p. Then what is the probability that sequence T,H,H,H will occur before the sequence H,H,H,H. or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can figure out that HHHH could win is if it is drawn immediately at the start so the answer is $p^4$.  This means the probablility of THHH winning is $1-p^4$.  For an even chance coin, $p = .5$ so $p^4=\frac{1}{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of both sequences occurring on their own, in 4 flips, is the same: $2^{-4}$.  However, T,H,H,H will happen more commonly in consecutive flips.  This is because when you fail to finish the sequence, it is because you flipped a tails, which means that you're already $1/4$ done *by failing*.  The other sequence doesn't have this benefit.  See if you can compute the probability using this knowledge.